# Trigger useEffect on an api call with query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a Search component using React Hooks and the main feature is when I put a Word inside my input, I make an API call with that word and it returns words that matches

Right now the component looks like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './SearchBar.css';

export function SearchBar() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
    console.log(event);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCities = query => {
      const uri = 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/v1/autocomplete/';
      axios
        .get(uri, {
          params: {
            q: query
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.filter(name =>
            name.toLowercase().includes(query)
          );
          setSearchResults(data);
          console.log('searchResults' + searchResults);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err); //I know this is nothign but im running out of time tbh
        });
    };

    fetchCities();
  }, [query]);

  const handleSubmit = evt => {
    /*  evt.preventDefault();
    alert(apiCall());
    reset(); */
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleChange} className='display'>
      <input
        type='text'
        placeholder='Search'
        onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' className='resize' />
      <ul>
        {searchResults.map(item => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div></div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Right now on page load I get this error

```
xhr.js:166 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/v1/autocomplete/ 400 (Bad Request)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:166
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:16
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:49
Promise.then (async)
```

When I only want the API call to be made when I submit the form. Any help ?

Comment: Are you still having issues with your code?

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` will get triggered when your component first mounts, so you need an `if` statement inside of it to decide whether you want to make the API call or not:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (query === "") return

  const fetchCities = query => {
    // ...
  }
  fetchCities()
}, [query])
```

But if you only want to trigger the API call when you submit the form, I would simplify your code:

```js
function SearchBar() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  // ...
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const uri = '...'
    axios.get(uri, { params: { q: query } })
      .then(response => {
        // ...
        setSearchResults(data)
      })
      .catch(err => { ... })
  }

  const handleQueryChange = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={handleQueryChange} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
      {...}
    </form>
  )
```

This way you're not calling your API endpoint every time you type in a new character into the `search` field. It will only get called once when you click `submit`.

See the following `CodeSandbox` link for an example:

- [CodeSandbox React hook form example](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-silence-nzj2j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

I did a little update on your code sample:

It looked to me that the main problem was that the fetch url was not running

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCities = qry => {
      const uri = "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5df693273400002900e5a5f3";

      axios
        .get(uri, {
          params: {
            q: qry
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.tags.filter(name =>
            name.toLowerCase().includes(qry)
          );
          setSearchResults(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("error", err); //I know this is nothign but im running out of time tbh
        });
    };

    fetchCities(query);
  }, [query]);

  const handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <form method="POST" onSubmit={handleChange} className="display">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="submit"
        onClick={handleSubmit}
        value="Submit"
        className="resize"
      />
      <ul>
        {searchResults.map(item => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <div />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```